# Deploy Lambda functions without binaries

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have some problems with serverless deploy, because when I deploy my Lambda function, the Serverless Framework start packing my node_modules, but it takes a lot of time.

I mean why to upload node_modules again if it have not been updated. Maybe somebody know, how deploy only a Lambda function code without packing binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [packaging configuration](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/).

In your **serverless.yml** file, add:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
```

It is useful to remove the AWS-SDK modules (because if you don't upload them, Lambda will use what AWS offers - which is better) and to remove dev modules (like testing frameworks). However, all other modules are dependencies and will be needed to be uploaded for your function to work properly. So, configure the package settings to include/exclude exactly what you need.

Regarding your other question

> why to upload node_modules again if it have not been updated

It is not a limitation of the Serverless Framework. It is a limitation of the AWS Lambda service. You **can't** make a partial upload of a Lambda function. Lambda always requires that the uploaded zip package contains the updated code and all required modules dependencies.

If your deploy is taking too long, maybe you should consider breaking this Lambda function into smaller units.